# How to use true/false inside definitions?

Tags: conditionals, sourcecode, pagestyle

Suppose you want to define page style depending on a boolean value.

I think both constructions below have equivalent output (or not?), but **which is better/more indicated/professional/elegant**?

```
\if@mybool
    \def\ps@myps{
        % definition here
    }
\else
    \def\ps@myps{
        % definition here
    }
\fi
```

or

```
\def\ps@myps{
    \if@mybool
        % definition here
    \else
        % definition here
    \fi
}
```

Comment: They aren't equivalent. The former tests `\if@mybool` at definition time, the latter at call time.

Comment: @egreg, oh, I see. But do you have some reason to choose one? I mean, could I get some bug or problem if I choose wrong?

Comment: The two constructs do *different* things, so generally only one is correct according to what you need to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two constructs *aren't* equivalent.

With

```
\if@mybool
  \def\ps@myps{...T...}%
\else
  \def\ps@myps{...F...}%
\fi
```

you test `\if@mybool` and define `\ps@myps` according to its truth value. Changing the value later in the document will not change the definition of `\ps@myps`.

To the contrary,

```
\def\ps@myps{%
  \if@mybool
    ...A...%
  \else
    ...B...%
  \fi
}
```

will yield `...A...` or `...B...` according the the truth value of `\if@mybool` at the time the macro is expanded.

Which one to use depends on what you need to achieve.

---

With the first definition, if issued when `\if@mybool` is true,

```
\@myboolfalse
\ps@myps
\@myboolfalse
\ps@myps
```

will produce `...A...` twice.

With the second definition, the above code would produce first `...B...` and then `...A...`.

If you are writing a package and `\if@mybool` is set by a package options at runtime, most likely you want to use the first model, as the macro name suggests you're trying to define a page style that probably shouldn't change mid document.

---

The situation is quite similar to `\let` and `\def`. With `\let\mymacro\another` you define `\mymacro` to be the same `\another` is at the time the `\let` instruction is performed.

With `\def\mymacro{\another}`, the meaning of `\another` current at the moment `\mymacro` is called will be used, which can have changed in the meantime.

Comment: *Changing the value later in the document will not change the definition of `\ps@myps`* explained a lot to me. Very nice!

Comment: @Sigur I added some more comments

Comment: I got it. That is the point, `mybool` will not change, because it comes from an option within the class. Thanks.